# Fail to curl to secure HTTP from local minikube cluster

Tags: jenkins, curl, istio, minikube, istio-sidecar

So, I have `minikube 0.16.0 installed`

Also `istio 1.7.3`

So I do envoy sidecars on each deployment I do, as per with command `kubectl label namespace default istio-injection=enabled`

Now, coming to the question, I'm not able to do any `curl` from inside any pod whatsoever, even from `sleep-diag`, I always get request timed out message, but it does work for non secure `http`

For example while installing `jenkins`, I try to `curl` against this `url` with no success:

```
bash-5.0# curl -v https://updates.jenkins.io/current/update-center.json
*   Trying 92.242.132.16:443...
* TCP_NODELAY set
* connect to 92.242.132.16 port 443 failed: Operation timed out
* Failed to connect to updates.jenkins.io port 443: Operation timed out
* Closing connection 0
curl: (28) Failed to connect to updates.jenkins.io port 443: Operation timed out
```

But even if I try let's say:

```
bash-5.0# curl -v https://www.google.com
*   Trying 92.242.132.16:443...
* TCP_NODELAY set
* connect to 92.242.132.16 port 443 failed: Operation timed out
* Failed to connect to www.google.com port 443: Operation timed out
* Closing connection 0
curl: (28) Failed to connect to www.google.com port 443: Operation timed out
```

While I'm able to outside of any `pod` in my local cluster, any ideas on this?

For example, tried installing `jenkins` like this, with `helm`:

```
helm install --set Master.ServiceType=ClusterIP jenkins/jenkins --generate-name
```

Obviously it will fail because I cannot access any `https` from my local cluster, even specifying `NodePort` I have the same issue:

```
helm install --set Master.ServiceType=NodePort jenkins/jenkins --generate-name
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Did you try with istio disabled ? Could you provide more detailed description of your setup so it can be reproduced ?

Comment: Alright, will edit my question in a bit with more details, no, haven't tried without istio, will give that a shot too